# Window list Panel Applet mouse shortcuts

Tags: applet

Is there a way that I can customize the Window List Panel Applet so that middle clicking closes a program or group of programs?

Comment: Other than downloading the source and editing it?

Answer (score 1):

The window list applet does not support this. A possible "solution" would be to try [dockbarx](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgnome-look.org%2Fcontent%2Fshow.php%3Fcontent%3D101604&rct=j&q=dockbarx&ei=P4DjTPjjE8G78gbC3unnDg&usg=AFQjCNGZqMg9TvIhF6XOFgJTTZnm3bBeaQ&sig2=63kbvlujGTRCJS5qpveUfA&cad=rja) and use that for managing windows. Please note though that this is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.  It's not a bad idea though (imo), and would be consistent with well-established behaviour in other tab-like things.  You could file it at http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/.  Or as Oli says, try to add it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I just altered the **extension.js** file that is part of **Window List**

Here is my altered version [extension.js](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/618944/extension-js.html)

This is the directory path it is stored in by the app: **/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com**

All you need to do is put the **extension.js** in your home folder and run these 2 commands

**--Backup original extension.js**

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com && sudo cp extension.js extension.js.bak
```

and

**-- Move replacement extension.js**

```
cd ~ && sudo mv extension.js /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
```